# Is autoresolving cherry pick conflicts possible?

Tags: git

Assume `develop` and `backport` git branches. Everyone creates PRs to the `develop` branch, so the `backport` branch lags behind. At one point I want to `cherry-pick` a commit from `develop` to the `backport`, but the two branches are so different at this point that there is a conflict.

I think programmatically it should be possible to autoresolve many of these conflicts or at least output which other commits should be cherry picked first to avoid conflicts completely.

An algorithm I have in mind for this:

1. Cherry pick a commit.
2. Is there conflict? If no: done.
3. If yes: where is the conflict and which other commit touched that previously?
4. Cherry pick the guilty commit and repeat this algorithm recursively.

So: is there a tool that automatically does this or something similar already?

Comment: In step 3, it sounds like you're assuming the conflict is because you're missing another commit on `develop` that you need. But couldn't it also be due to a conflict with a new commit on `backport`?

Comment: Also, even if you can do this, you need to cherry pick multiple commits in the order they occurred, so step 4 would be more like, "throw this away and start over, cherry pick the 2nd commit we found in step 4, then the first commit we used in step 1".